# RewriteRule is redirecting rather than rewriting

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have a rewrite rule that looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ store [L]
```

That's the only thing in the .htaccess file.

It's supposed to allow someone to go to http://www.site.com/ and according to the server, they're accessing http://www.site.com/store .

But it's redirecting the user. In other words, you see "/store" in the URL. How do I avoid this?

By the way, there's not a redirect going on within /store/index.php (the index script in the store directory. I know this because I put a die statement in there and the "/store" is in the URL when the script dies on that script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, I changed it from

```
RewriteRule ^$ store [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^$ /store/ [L]
```

and it started working